# Partner Community Records Sharing

Tags: community, filters, partner-communities, partner-portal

I have a custom object on which their is a look to Account. Now i want to show all records in Service Provider Community where Custom field Account is equals to service provider's  Account. I am not sure how can i do this using standard way the list view is standard list view and we can not create custom list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [sharing sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_setting_light_users.htm&type=5). This will allow you to share all records that match the user's account with them. Note this will mean you need to make the public [org wide sharing for that object private](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sharing.htm&type=5) (the setting for external users, not internal). Also, sharing sets are only supported with Salesforce Community Licenses, if your org is like ours and you use a custom license (we have a really old org) these won't be supported.

**Disclaimer:** I'd normally quote the source material; however, it's kinda long. Also, if the material disappears that means its deprecated and no longer valid anyway.

Comment: Maybe. A lot of links broke in Summer '18 documentation (at least, Google's indexes seem to miss often now). That said, I agree it's too long for a reasonable answer, and easy enough to Google if it moves.